# Android Gridview setEmptyView

Tags: android, gridview, view

I'm obviously missing something little.  I have an android gridview set up and I have a textview set as the emptyview.  The emptyview shows up fine when there's no data, but when there is data, the emptyview doesn't go away and no data is shown.  I thought maybe this would automatically happen.  What am I forgetting?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have set an Adapter for your GridView ? (cf : [myGridView.setAdapter(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#setAdapter%28android.widget.ListAdapter%29) )

If you're using an ArrayAdapter, do you make a call to [myArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) ?

Comment: That was it, forgot the notify.  o.0 Thanks!